# How to remove duplicates according to an extra condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following code to remove the duplicates of a dataframe based on a given key:

Input:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({"A":["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar"],  "B":["A","A","B","A"], "C":[0,3,1,1]})
dff.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep=False)
```

Output:

```
     A  B  C
2  foo  B  1
3  bar  A  1
```

But how can I group by the same key, but selecting the row which has a larger number in "C" column. I mean, the desired output would be:

```
     A  B  C
2  foo  B  3
3  bar  A  1
```

Comment: If you use `keep=False` you will lose the row with C=3 regardless. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Do you want `dff.sort_values('C', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], keep='first')`?

Comment: How do you get `foo  B  3` from the sample data you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need overwrite your column C with `group` `max` before you drop duplicate

```
dff.C=dff.groupby('A').C.transform('max')
dff.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep=False)
Out[325]: 
     A  B  C
2  foo  B  3
3  bar  A  1
```